# Not in scope: data constructor

Tags: haskell

I wrote a program with `haskell` but I got errors from ghci

here is the source codes,I construct it, and if I have

```
p1 :: Prop
p1 = And (Var 'A') (Not (Var 'A'))
```

It will show `A && ~A` so that is the source codes

```
import Data.List
import Data.Char
data Prop = Const Bool | 
        Var Char | 
        Not Prop | 
        And Prop Prop | 
        Or Prop Prop | 
        Imply Prop Prop
        deriving Eq
instance Show Prop where
  show (Var Char) = show Char
  show (Not Prop) = "(~" ++ show Prop ++ ")"
  show (And Prop Prop) = "(" ++ show Prop ++ "&&" ++ show Prop ++ ")"
  show (Or Prop Prop) = "(" ++ show Prop "||" ++ show Prop ++ ")"
  show (Imply Prop Prop) = "(" ++ show Prop "=>" show Prop ++ ")"
```

And I got two main errors from ghci...

```
Not in scope: data constructor `Char'
Not in scope: data constructor `Prop'
```

I am a beginner with haskell,thankyou very much.

Comment: _Please_ don't use `Show` for this and write your own `Prop -> String` function; it will help you down the track!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Value names that start with an uppercase letter are reserved for *constructors*, like `Var`, `True`, `False`, etc. Variables must start with a lowercase letter.

Additionally, you can't use the same name for two different variables. How would Haskell know which one you meant each time you used them? You can't simply use the definition of a constructor as a pattern in a function; you need to give a separate name to each field.

So, instead of `Var Char`, write `Var name`; instead of `Imply Prop Prop`, write `Imply p q` (or `Imply prop1 prop2`), and so on.

Answer (score 3):

A slight edit will get it working:

```
instance Show Prop where
  show (Var c) = [c]
  show (Not p) = "(~" ++ show p ++ ")"
  show (And p1 p2) = "(" ++ show p1 ++ " && " ++ show p2 ++ ")"
  show (Or p1 p2) = "(" ++ show p1 ++ "||" ++ show p2 ++ ")"
  show (Imply p1 p2) = "(" ++ show p1 ++ "=>" ++ show p2 ++ ")"
```

Comment: Hello, thankyou for your answers, but I found a problem. The `p1` above, the real answer is `A && ~A`, and your answer is `('A'&&~'A')`

Comment: Getting rid of the quotes is easy - applying `show` to a Char produces a quoted character, but since a String is just a list of Chars, you can make the Char show non-quoted by just making it into a one-element list.  Dealing with the parens will be more challenging, if you don't want them to always be there.  Surely they'll need to be there sometimes.

Comment: Thankyou, It works, I appreciate your help and your explanation