# Haskell parser to AST data type - parse error on input `|'

Tags: parsing, haskell

I am struggeling with an assignment we have been given. I have written this code slightly based on a different guide here: [Not in scope: data constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476050/not-in-scope-data-constructor)

The problem i have is a the pipe here:

```
| x == "+" = (Sum y y',xs'') where
```

The problem seems to be related to having 3 pipes or a pipe following a "where". If i swap the 2 last pipes.
Putting

```
x == "+"  = (Sum y y' (...))
```

before

```
x == "*"  = (Prod y y' (...))
```

causes the error to move to that code. If i comment out any one of these two code segments everything works fine, but i need both of them for the assignment we have been given.

Quick summary:

```
| x == "*" = (Prod y y',xs'') where
                (y,xs') = ast xs
                (y',xs'') = ast xs'
```

and

```
| x == "+" = (Sum y y',xs'') where
                (y,xs') = ast xs
                (y',xs'') = ast xs'
```

both work 100% alone, but when i put them together my program does not compile.

Full code:

```
import Data.Char

data AST = Leaf Int 
            | Sum AST AST 
            | Min AST 
            | Prod AST AST
            deriving Show

tokenize::String -> [String]
tokenize[] = []
tokenize('+':xs) = "+": tokenize xs
tokenize('-':xs) = "-": tokenize xs
tokenize('*':xs) = "*": tokenize xs
tokenize(x:xs) = if isDigit x then (takeWhile isDigit (x:xs)) : tokenize (dropWhile isDigit xs) else tokenize(xs)

ast :: [String] -> (AST,[String])
ast [] = error "Empty string"
ast (x:xs) | all isDigit x = (Leaf (read x),xs)
    | x == "-" = let (y,xs') = ast xs in (Min y,xs')
    | x == "*" = (Prod y y',xs'') where
            (y,xs') = ast xs
            (y',xs'') = ast xs'
    | x == "+" = (Sum y y',xs'') where
            (y,xs') = ast xs
            (y',xs'') = ast xs'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem in

```
ast [] = error "Empty string"
ast (x:xs) | all isDigit x = (Leaf (read x),xs)
    | x == "-" = let (y,xs') = ast xs in (Min y,xs')
    | x == "*" = (Prod y y',xs'') where
            (y,xs') = ast xs
            (y',xs'') = ast xs'
    | x == "+" = (Sum y y',xs'') where
            (y,xs') = ast xs
            (y',xs'') = ast xs'
```

is that you can have only one `where` clause per equation in the function definition. So after the `where` in the `x == "*"` alternative, the parser expects the equation for the pattern `(x:xs)` to be complete.

Just remove the offending `where`, the `where` clause is scoped over all the alternatives in the equation, and both `where` clauses have the same contents (and indent it nicer, the `where` belongs on its own line according to my preferences). Since the `let` in the first alternative uses a binding also present in the `where` clause, that can also be removed:

```
ast [] = error "Empty string"
ast (x:xs) | all isDigit x = (Leaf (read x),xs)
    | x == "-" = (Min y,xs')
    | x == "*" = (Prod y y',xs'')
    | x == "+" = (Sum y y',xs'')
      where
        (y,xs') = ast xs
        (y',xs'') = ast xs'
```

Answer (score 1):

One way round this is to use `let` instead of `where`:

```
ast :: [String] -> (AST,[String])
ast [] = error "Empty string"
ast (x:xs) | all isDigit x = (Leaf (read x),xs)
    | x == "-" = let (y,xs') = ast xs in (Min y,xs')
    | x == "*" = let
            (y,xs') = ast xs 
            (y',xs'') = ast xs'
            in (Prod y y',xs'')
    | x == "+" = let 
            (y,xs') = ast xs
            (y',xs'') = ast xs'
            in (Sum y y',xs'')
```

You can have as many definitions as you like inside a `let`, not just one.

`where` statements are in scope to the end, whereas `let` finishes at the `in`. That's why you got the error message - it thought you were still in the `where`, but you wanted to carry on. Postpone your `where` clauses right to the end.

In this case, you didn't need to have them seperate, so could have combined them into a single where, but `let` is useful for this problem generally.