# How to call a function returning a tuple in another function in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have two functions like these:

```
notice_objects_at::String -> IO()
notice_objects_at place = do
  let (X,Y) = at place
  putStrLn ("There is a" ++ show X ++ "," ++ show Y ++ "here.")
  putStrLn "Hi" 

at::String-> (String, String)
at place =
  case place of
    "bedroom" -> ("fly", "light switch")
    "den" -> ("flyswatter", "light switch")
```

from the 'at' function I am returning a tuple, which I want to store to two variables X and Y in the notice_objects_at function. But, I'm getting an error that:

```
Not in scope: data constructor ‘X’
Not in scope: data constructor ‘Y’
Not in scope: data constructor ‘X’
Not in scope: data constructor ‘Y’
```

What is wrong?

Comment: `x` instead of `X`, `y` instead of `Y`. Only types and modules start with capital letters.

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed as a typographical error. It's a "small" error, but not typographical: the `X` was used on purpose, and is a real language problem, not just some fat-finger on the keyboard.

Comment: "Only types and modules start with capital letters" and data constructors, evidently.

Comment: @amalloy: My reasoning is that *the stated question* was "caused by... a simple typographical error." I can imagine a rephrased question to which DNA's answer would be appropriate and which would be on topic. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476050/not-in-scope-data-constructor).

Answer (score 2):

Haskell syntax relies on the capitalisation of names. As described [here](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2012/09/ten-things-you-should-know-about-haskell-syntax):

> Anything that starts with a capital letter is either a concrete type
>   or a data constructor. Lower-case-starting names are reserved for
>   function names and variables, including type variables.

So when you bind names to the elements of the tuple in:

```
let (X,Y) = at place
```

you need lowercase names:

```
let (x,y) = at place
```

(and adjust the names wherever else they are used, of course!)

Otherwise Haskell interprets these names as data constructors, but of course cannot find their definition anywhere, hence your error messages.

See also [Why does Haskell force data constructor's first letter to be upper case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237775/why-does-haskell-force-data-constructors-first-letter-to-be-upper-case)